# Setting state values based on an array value React + ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a state variable in react as:

```
this.state = {
    formStatus : {
        approved : true,
        rejected : true,
        pending  : true
    }
}
```

and a dynamic array whose value can contain either one or all of these values

```
appliedFilters = ['approved', 'rejected', 'pending']
```

Now What I want to do is set my state keys to false if the array doesn't contain them.

For example, if the array is `['approved', 'rejected']` then my state should be set as:

```
this.state = {
    formStatus : {
        approved : true,
        rejected : true,
        pending  : false
    }
}
```

I want to do it using **ES6 map()** if possible.

I have done something like this but it is not working:

```
appliedFilters.map(filter => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        formStatus: prevState.formStatus.map(
            status => (status === filter) ? true : false
        )
    }))
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't build an object using a map. And you don't want `forEach` because there's no need for mutation here. Maps work on (and return) collections. You should use `reduce`.

```
const appliedFilters = ['approved', 'rejected']

const state = ['approved', 'rejected', 'pending'].reduce((newState, item) => ({
    ...newState,
    [item]: appliedFilters.includes(item)
}), {});

this.setState(state);
```

Comment: this actually doesn't work properly. setting state of invalid structure here.. fix it by `this.setState({  formStatus: state  })`

Comment: i figured that out...... however can you explain to me the purpose of empty {} in the reduce function you used.

Comment: It's called 'accumulator'. Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @streletss i think you meant initial value. Initialize state with empty object

Comment: Yes it's the initial value, it's what `newState` will be the first time the reduce callback is executed. It's an object here, but if you were, say, adding numbers together in a reducer, the initial value might just be `0`, and you keep adding to it and returning the new accumulated value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible `Array.prototype.map`, because the `map` function return new Array()....

Try do this.

```
const allFilters = ['approved', 'rejected', 'pending'];
const appliedFilters = ['approved', 'rejected'];

const newState = {};
allFilters.forEach(filter => {
    newState[filter] = appliedFilters.includes(filter);
});

// use!!!
newState;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't call `.map` on `prevState.formStatus`. It's an object, not array.
2. Avoid calling `this.setState` on every iteration of `.map`.

You could consider simply doing this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  formStatus: Object
    .keys(prevState.formStatus)
    .reduce((acc, stat) => ({ ...acc, [stat]: appliedFilters.includes(stat) }), {}) 
}))
```